# express.static + middlware = 404

Tags: node.js, express

This works:

```
http://localhost:3000/private/test2.html
app.use('/private',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'private')));
```

However as soon as I add middleware, the page can't be found.

```
var secure = function(req,res,next) {
    console.log('in here' + req.url);
    next();
}
app.use('/private',secure,express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'private')));
```

With the middleware in place I get a 404. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the middleware to this :

```
app.use(secure);
// use the middleware function

app.use('/private',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'private')));
// serve static files from private subfolder using 'private/' as  matching prefix
// static should be used at the end as it finishes the response.
```

Comment: Thanks, I was getting mixed up with app.get and app.use

Answer (score 0):

`app.use` only takes one parameter. you need to split it into two `app.use()`s.